# How to change layer depth according to player location?

Tags: c#, monogame, depth-buffer, draw-order

I would like to change the layer depth of objects, so that the player can go behind them. Right now it looks like this when the player is behind the object:

[image]

The problem is that the layer depth doesn't take into account the players location in relation to the object, so it doesn't look correct when the player is in front of the object:

[image]

What would be a good way to accomplish this? Could it be done just by comparing the locations of collision boxes (green boxes in the image) when they overlap? Or should I calculate and change the depth for all objects currently on-screen? How could I do that?

Thanks.

**[UPDATE]**

Here is the draw call from the base class for game objects:

```
public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {

        if (texture != null && Active == true) {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color, 0f, Vector2.Zero, Scale, SpriteEffects.None, LayerDepth);
        }

        DrawCollision(spriteBatch); // DEBUG

}
```

It's an overload of the built-in MonoGame `SpriteBatch.Draw()` function. The thing that determines the draw order is `LayerDepth`. LayerDepth is a property inside each object. Currently it is just set to a fixed value.

Comment: Whenever an object moves you can update its layer (Z value?) based on the Y value of its "foot" where it looks like it would intersect the ground. I think that's probably related to the cyan line in your screenshot.

Comment: @Romen What would I compare the Y-value to, though? Can I somehow compare it to the Y-values of other objects on-screen? What would I use as a reference for changing the value? I think the layer depth can be from 0f to 1f. The green box is basically the collision for the texture, and the cyan box is collision for movement.

Comment: Make a deterministic formula to set the depth based on the Y value and set the depth of everything based on the Y value. If the top of the world is Y = 0 (world coordinates, not screen) and the bottom is Y = 1000 then your Z could be set to `z = y / 1000` to scale it between 0 1 as you go from the top (back) to bottom (front) of the world.

Comment: @Romen Hmm, yeah, I thought about something like that actually. But what if I don't necessarily know the size of the world? Like if the world is procedurally generated, for example? Should it be done in screen coordinates?

Comment: Yes you could do it relative to the screen but make sure to handle things that are "off screen" like a tree below the bottom of the view but you can still see the higher branches over everything.

Comment: How are you setting `LayerDepth` currently?

Comment: I have it set to a fixed value currently, as I don't have any method for changing it yet. I know that I'll need to consider the location of the object in relation to other objects, but I don't know how/where I should update the value and what I would use to change the value, since the layer depth value has to be within a certain value range. @DMGregory

Comment: What certain value range does it need to be in?

Comment: I believe the value should be between 0.0f-1.0f @DMGregory

Answer (score 0):

> How do I change layer depth according to player location? ... How could I do that?

Sort the `Draw()` calls by "location".

You have given two 2D images and no code. Without code, it is not possible to be more specific.

Comment: I just use an overload of the built in MonoGame `SpriteBatch.Draw()` function for draw calls. I added the draw call code as an update to the post. The thing that determines the draw order in the overload is `LayerDepth`. LayerDepth is a property inside each object.